# Data structure capacity

Tags: java, data-structures

I got a simple POJO made of 22 fields which are read from few CSV files.
The reader thread reads the files line by line and where each line contains values for these 22 fields and constructs the POJO. Each object is stored in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

The catch is the overall number of lines is approx 3 million. I am running my program from Eclipse in dual CPU machine with each having 8 cores in it. I use -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m VM argument.

The problem is that after reading near 800000 lines, constructing POJO for each of line and offering the POJO to queue, I get OutOfMemory error for heap space.

My question is can these many objects be stored in a the queue without getting OutOfMemory problem anyway?

Comment: that depends on the type of the 22 fields in your object

Comment: It is not about the queue capacity. In the 22 fields what are you storing? and what would be the typical size of one object? multiply that by 800000 and see if you are exceeding the 1GB RAM or not

Comment: thanks Katona and Teja. However even though my machine got 8GB RAM, I can't give VM argument as -Xmx2048m. is it because I am running it via eclipse?

Comment: Sure, if you have enough memory to hold all your objects. I don't know why you can't give your VM that much memory unless you have some sort of process limit in place or your OS is funky.

Comment: @user2654241
why not? what's the problem? you should be able to do it via the [launch configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm)

Comment: Well, as already mentioned that this OOM is because of those 800k objects, and there is no way out apart from alloting more memory if you want to store all 3 million objects in that queue. If there is no inter-dependency in those 3 million lines data, then you can store less than 800k objects in queue and process them and clear the queue, and then start loading other lines. But it all depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are just consuming all of the available memory. The JVM tries everithing before throwing OutOfMemoryError, so you cannot do anything except for increasing your heap size ->  -Xmx2g (for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you are curious exactly what fills your heap, try launching the jvm with the *-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError* argument. A heap dump will be created when the out of memory error occurs, and you can open it using [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) or [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Comment: It's pretty obvious that it's the 800000 instances of the POJOs

Comment: true, but you can see the overhead of the _LinkedBlockingQueue_, which  might be significant if the POJOs size is relatively small, then you may change your datastructure